# creating a backend data storage for quick retrieval

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am writing a software which stores all the information of a users interaction in a global session object/class. I would like to store this values collected in a persistent storage. However  i cannot use heavy databases such as sql server or mysql in the target pc as i need to keep the installer minimum in size.

I also need to retrieve values from the storage by passing simple Linq queries,etc.

My question is what is the next best thing to databases which can be manipulated by C# code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably either [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) or [SQL Server Compact Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/compact.aspx) - these are both fairly full-featured database systems than run entirely in-process and are frequently used these sorts of thing (for example Firefox uses SQLite to store bookmarks).

The next rung down the ladder of complexity would probably be either XML (using LINQ to XML), or just serialisable objects (using LINQ to objects) - you would of course incur performance penalties over a "proper" compact database like SQLite if you started storing a lot of data, however you would probably need store more than you think before it became noticable, and for small data sets the simplicity would even make this faster than SQLite (for example you could restrict your application to storing the last 100 or so actions).

Answer (score 2):

[SQL Server CE](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/compact.aspx) and [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) are popular for the scenario you are describing. XML is as well

Comment: XML sounds like a promising option.

Answer (score 0):

You could connect to Access MDB files. You don't need an SQL server for this, and it uses the same syntax.
Just need to use OleDb.

Example: [DataEasy: Connect to MS Access (.mdb) Files Easily using C#](http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=1930&lngWId=10)